# How do you represent a list [x, y] coordinates into a graph on python?

Tags: python, graph, coordinates

My current output is set out as such

```
[2, 9]
[2, 8]
[2, 7]
[3, 7]
```

and I would like it to display on a 20x20 grid

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: And beside the missing code from you it is unclear what you want. Show us the desired output/result also please.

Comment: If you're talking about text output – loop over the y coordinates for each row, loop over the x coordinates for that row, find whether you have `(x, y)` in your list of coordinates and print out an `x` or `.`?

Comment: If this is a homework question I would recommend to try a list with 20 strings each with a length of 20 characters. Show us that you tried yourself with some code then we can help you.

Comment: I have fine working answer code. But you have to come first. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears that you would like to plot your output as a scatter plot on a 20x20 grid. You'll need to use the `matplotlib` package (`pip install matplotlib` should work). If you save your output as a list of lists, you can use list comprehension like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# You'll need to figure out how to save your output this way
points = [[2, 9], [2, 8], [2, 7], [3, 7]] 
# setting the window to be [0, 20]
plt.xlim([0, 20])
plt.ylim([0, 20])
# plot the graph
plt.scatter(x=[x[0] for x in points], y=[y[1] for y in points])
```

[image: scatter plot of the output]